# Get quantity per product in each order using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables, `order`, `products`, and `orders_products` and I'm trying to find out how many of each product was bought in each order. Is it possible to get all information in a single query?

My current query doesn't seem to work, whereas the `product_id` comes out as all the same.

```
SELECT orders.order_id, orders.username, COUNT( DISTINCT op.product_id ) product_id, SUM( op.quantity ) quantity
FROM  `orders` 
JOIN orders_products op ON op.order_id = orders.order_id
GROUP BY product_id, orders.order_id ORDER BY order_id, product_id
```

Which results in:

```
_______________________________________________
| order_id | username | product_id | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          1 |        3 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          1 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          1 |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        2 | sally    |          1 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          1 |        6 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          1 |        7 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

You can see the problem above in the `product_id` column which is always set to `1`.

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
_______________________________________________
| order_id | username | product_id | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          1 |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          2 |        3 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          3 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        2 | sally    |          1 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          1 |        6 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          2 |        7 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

My tables:

```
-- Orders
_______________________
| order_id | username |
-----------------------
|        1 | bill     |
-----------------------
|        2 | sally    |
-----------------------
|        3 | jeff     |
-----------------------

-- Products
___________________
|    id | product |
-------------------
|     1 | Table   |
-------------------
|     2 | Chair   |
-------------------
|     3 | Mouse   |
-------------------

-- Order Products
___________________________________________
|   id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
-------------------------------------------
|    1 |        1 |          1 |        5 |
-------------------------------------------
|    2 |        1 |          2 |        3 |
-------------------------------------------
|    3 |        1 |          3 |        2 |
-------------------------------------------
|    4 |        2 |          1 |        2 |
-------------------------------------------
|    5 |        3 |          1 |        6 |
-------------------------------------------
|    6 |        3 |          2 |        7 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you are already getting in the same data in third table..show how are you searching user name, also user table structure

Comment: @DevLakshman The user table is the `orders` table at least in the example data. But I also think there are missing information or at least the example data is already summed up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.username, op.product_id, SUM( op.quantity ) as quantity
FROM  `orders` o JOIN 
      orders_products op
      ON op.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY op.product_id, o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id, op.product_id;
```

In general, you do want all the columns in the `GROUP BY` in the `SELECT`.  But (in general) they shouldn't be arguments to aggregation functions such as `COUNT()`.

Comment: This is great. I'm using this query right now. I made a follow-up question to this which uses columns instead of rows. Do you mind taking a look at it as well? It's in [MYSQL: Separate products into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910164/mysql-separate-products-into-columns).

Answer (score 0):

> You can see the problem above in the product_id column which is always
>   set to 1

I think you are bit confused here, that's the data present in `Order Products` table for `product_id` column but in your query what you are trying to get is count of data `COUNT( DISTINCT op.product_id ) product_id` and since the count is `1`, the result is showing the same.