# MYSQL: Separate products into columns

Tags: mysql

This is in relation to my previous post [MYSQL: Get quantity per product in each order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874996/mysql-get-quantity-per-product-in-each-order).

Using the query below, it generates a table of:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.username, op.product_id, SUM( op.quantity ) as quantity
FROM  `orders` o JOIN 
      orders_products op
      ON op.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY op.product_id, o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id, op.product_id;

_______________________________________________
| order_id | username | product_id | quantity |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          1 |        5 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          2 |        3 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |          3 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        2 | sally    |          1 |        2 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          1 |        6 |
-----------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |          2 |        7 |
-----------------------------------------------
```

As seen above, each new `product_id` is assigned its own row. Is it possible to have additional columns for each `product_id` instead of rows generating an output same as the one below?

```
_______________________________________________________________________
| order_id | username | product_qty_1 | product_qty_2 | product_qty_3 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|        1 | bill     |             5 |             3 |             2 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|        2 | sally    |             2 |             0 |             0 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|        3 | jeff     |             6 |             7 |             0 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My tables:

```
-- Orders
_______________________
| order_id | username |
-----------------------
|        1 | bill     |
-----------------------
|        2 | sally    |
-----------------------
|        3 | jeff     |
-----------------------

-- Products
___________________
|    id | product |
-------------------
|     1 | Table   |
-------------------
|     2 | Chair   |
-------------------
|     3 | Mouse   |
-------------------

-- Order Products
___________________________________________
|   id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
-------------------------------------------
|    1 |        1 |          1 |        5 |
-------------------------------------------
|    2 |        1 |          2 |        3 |
-------------------------------------------
|    3 |        1 |          3 |        2 |
-------------------------------------------
|    4 |        2 |          1 |        2 |
-------------------------------------------
|    5 |        3 |          1 |        6 |
-------------------------------------------
|    6 |        3 |          2 |        7 |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: yikes that could be scary wide

Comment: You have to use dynamic QL.

Comment: You are looking for `pivot table`. It is already answered how to sole the task in different ways. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the products in advance, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT o.order_id, o.username,
       SUM(CASE WHEN op.product_id = 1 THEN op.quantity ELSE 0 END) as quantity1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN op.product_id = 2 THEN op.quantity ELSE 0 END) as quantity2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN op.product_id = 3 THEN op.quantity ELSE 0 END) as quantity3
FROM  `orders` o JOIN 
      orders_products op
      ON op.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id;
```

If you don't know the product ids, then you would have to use dynamic SQL, or perhaps use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to create a string with the information you want.

Comment: You did it again, Gordon! Superb.